# Firebase Cloud Functions: how to get data from `change` and `context`?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

The [Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions Migration Guide: Beta to version 1.0](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff) documentation says that the Cloud Function trigger `onUpdate` parameters are now `(change, context)`. If I log `change` I get a object:

```
Change {
  before: 
   QueryDocumentSnapshot {
     _ref: DocumentReference { _firestore: [Object], _referencePath: [Object] },
     _fieldsProto: { word: [Object] },
     _readTime: undefined,
     _createTime: '2018-04-10T15:37:11.775234000Z',
     _updateTime: '2018-04-10T15:58:06.388975000Z' },
  after: 
   QueryDocumentSnapshot {
     _ref: DocumentReference { _firestore: [Object], _referencePath: [Object] },
     _fieldsProto: { word: [Object] },
     _readTime: undefined,
     _createTime: '2018-04-10T15:37:11.775234000Z',
     _updateTime: '2018-04-10T15:58:06.388975000Z' } }
```

The documentation says that I can get the data from this object with `change.before.val()` and `change.after.val()`. But logging `change.before.val()` results in this error message:

```
TypeError: change.before.val is not a function
```

Logging `change.after.val()` produces this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
```

Logging `context` results in this object, which doesn't include the data I want:

```
{ eventId: 'a981ffc3-a07a-4b17-8698-0f3ef6207ced-0',
  timestamp: '2018-04-10T17:03:00.699887Z',
  eventType: 'google.firestore.document.update',
  resource: 
   { service: 'firestore.googleapis.com',
     name: 'projects/languagetwo-cd94d/databases/(default)/documents/Oxford_Dictionaries/Word_Request' },
  params: { Word_Request: 'Word_Request' } }
```

Do the `(change, context)` parameters only work with Realtime Database and not with Cloud Firestore?

Here's my code:

```
exports.oxfordPronunciation = functions.firestore.document('Oxford_Dictionaries/{Word_Request}').onUpdate((change, context) => {

console.log(change);

  let options = {
    url: 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/ace/pronunciations%3B%20regions%3Dus',
    headers: {
      'app_id': 'TDK',
      'app_key': 'swordfish'
    }
  };

  function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var word = JSON.parse(body);
      admin.firestore().collection('Oxford_Dictionaries').doc('Word_Response').set({ 'token': word });
    }
  }

  request(options, callback);
  return 0;
});
```

Here are my Node modules:

```
npm list --depth=0 
functions@ /Users/TDK/LanguageTwo/functions
├── firebase-admin@5.12.0
├── firebase-functions@1.0.1
└── request@2.85.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#cloud-firestore) you need to use `data()` instead of `val()`:

```
exports.dbWrite = functions.firestore.document('/path').onWrite((change, context) => {
const beforeData = change.before.data(); // data before the write
const afterData = change.after.data(); // data after the write
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just saw that in the "Extend Cloud Firebase with Cloud Functions" documentation!